# ajax request callback calls another function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've written a function to validate username in my website

```
//Check username
//Check if the length is greater than 3 and no username already exists. Several other checks included

$('#username').blur(function()
{

        var v=this.value;
        if(v == "")
        {
            addPopover(this,'This field is required!');
            $('#username_group').removeClass("has-success").addClass("has-error");
            $('#username_feedback').removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
        }
        else if(username.length < 4)
        {
            addPopover(this,'The username must be atleast 4 characters long');
            $('#username_group').removeClass("has-success").addClass("has-error");
            $('#username_feedback').removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
        }
        else
        {
            $.post('php/check_username_avail.php',{ username : v },function(data){

                    if(data == "false")
                    {
                        alert('false occurred');
                        addPopover(this,'Sorry! this username is already taken.');
                        $('#username_group').removeClass("has-success").addClass("has-error");
                        $('#username_feedback').removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
                        alert('false ended');
                    }
                    else if(data == "true")
                    {
                        alert('true occurred');
                        removePopover(this);
                        $('#username_group').addClass("has-success").removeClass("has-error");
                        $('#username_feedback').addClass("glyphicon-ok").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
                        alert('true ended');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('else occurred!');
                        addPopover(this,data);
                        $('#username_group').removeClass("has-success").addClass("has-error");
                        $('#username_feedback').removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
                        alert('else ended');
                    }
                }).error(function(){
                    alert("An error occurred. Unable to validate username");
                });
        }
});


//function to add popover
function addPopover(id,message)
{
    alert("in add popover");
    $(id).attr("data-toggle","popover");
    $(id).attr("data-trigger","focus");
    $(id).attr("data-placement","left");
    $(id).attr("data-content",message);
    $(id).popover();
    alert('add popover ended');
}

//function to remove popover
function removePopover(id)
{
    alert("in remove popover");
    $(id).removeAttr("data-toggle");
    $(id).removeAttr("data-trigger");
    $(id).removeAttr("data-placement");
    $(id).removeAttr("data-content");
    alert("remove popover ended");
}
```

When data is false, I see 4 alerts i.e "false occurred","in add popover","add popover ended" and "false ended" in the same order.

but still the attributes I have added in addPopover function are not getting added. Why is it so?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can test easier ?

Comment: @Mestrum I don't know how to create fiddle for ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this" inside post callback function is not what you expect.

```
$('#username').blur(function() {
    var that = this,
        v = this.value;
    //...
    $.post('php/check_username_avail.php', { username : v }, function(data) {
        //...
        addPopover(that,'Sorry! this username is already taken.');
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```